# How could I switch <a href="/main/@{{item.id}}"> to v-bind:href in Vue2.0?

Tags: vue.js

I want to splice attribute like href use `v-bind:href` in vue2?

for example `<a href="/main/@{{item.id}}">` to `v-bind:href="/main/@{{item.id}}"`

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like following:

```
<a v-bind:href="'/main/' +item.id" />
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer